# Generating more samples of a random vector by convex combinations

Tags: sampling, random-variable, density-function, density-estimation

I am not sure if my question is reasonable but I am wondering if there's someone who has seen a familiar idea elsewhere.

Consider a random vector $X$ and let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be $n$ realizations of $X$. The probability law of $X$ cannot be analytically computed. Let $D$ be the range of $X$. It is known that $D$ is bounded and convex. Now, consider $D' \subset D$ which is of particular interest. My goal is to generate more samples of the conditional random vector $X | D'$. Is it possible to do this by only using the observations $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be $n$ that are contained in $D'$? I am not considering bootstrapping as the samples obtained are not "new".

Rather, is it possible to take convex combinations of observations of $X$ in $D'$ to generate more samples of $X | D'$? The weights of the convex combinations would then be dependent on which areas of $D'$ are more dense (in terms of the number of observations there) over the others.

References would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wondering about your notation $X \mid D'$...are you trying to sample from a 'truncated' version of the distribution of $X$ (where the density at all points outside $D'$ is forced to zero)?

Comment: Yes, in a sense because that's also how conditional densities would work. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep. Also, is $D'$ a convex set? Seems like some restrictions might be necessary if not.

Comment: Not necessarily. However, the bounds for $D'$ are not fixed. It's just a region of interest that I select qualitatively. We can make it convex as desired. I.e. I am willing to adapt $D'$ so that the set contains properties for which I could attain the objective above...

Comment: The answer clearly is "no," because you have only crude information about the relative probabilities of the measurable sets in $D^\prime$. You are basically asking how to generate more realizations from the law of $X$ after observing $n$ of them.  This requires estimating the law of $X$ in the first place--and your estimate won't be perfect, either.

Comment: Right, I know I only have crude information but are there no methods to generate more samples that are approximately distributed in this manner?

I cannot use kernel density estimation for estimating the law of $X$ because $X$ happens to be high-dimensional (like $R^{200}$)